# Getting the top 3 for one specific field

Tags: ms-access

I have the following query where I need to select the top 3 trainings for each job group. So I need each job group to return their 3 highest trainings. The code so far is

```
SELECT Mgmt_Lvl.MGMT_LVL, Book6.[Item ID], Book6.Description, Count(Book6.[User ID]) AS [CountOfUser ID]
FROM Mgmt_Lvl INNER JOIN ((Book6 INNER JOIN O896IA_VEMPPRSA ON Book6.[User ID] = O896IA_VEMPPRSA.SYS_EMP_ID_NR) INNER JOIN O867IA_VPJOBCO ON O896IA_VEMPPRSA.JOB_CLS_CD = O867IA_VPJOBCO.JOB_CLS_CD) ON Mgmt_Lvl.JOB_GRP_CD = O867IA_VPJOBCO.JOB_GRP_CD
GROUP BY Mgmt_Lvl.MGMT_LVL, Book6.[Item ID], Book6.Description
ORDER BY Count(Book6.[User ID]) DESC;

Count(Book6.[User ID]) AS [CountOfUser ID]
```

is the field I need the top 3 of

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a common table expression (CTE) with the row_number() function.

It's hard to get a grasp of the field you want counted by referencing it as "job group." I don't see a field by that name. That being said, here is a basic example of the query you want. If you replace the fields appropriately, it should give you the desired output.

```
WITH CTE_NAME (COL1, COL2, JOB_GROUP, ROWNUM)
AS
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY JOB_GROUP ORDER BY JOB_GROUP)
      , COL1
      , COL3
      , JOB_GROUP
FROM TABLE A
JOIN TABLE B
ON A.KEY = B.KEY
)

SELECT * 
FROM CTE_NAME
WHERE ROWNUM IN ('1','2','3')
ORDER BY JOB_GROUP
```

Explanation: "PARTITION BY" separates your data into groups based on the field you enter. When you add the ROW_NUMBER() function, you are assigning a unique row number for each record within the grouping you created. So, by selecting ROWNUMs '1', '2', '3', you essentially select the TOP 3 rows for each group. Just be sure you ORDER BY the correct field in your CTE expression.